# Elastic Beanstalk App in VPC Can't Be Accessed Publicly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I created a VPC and an EBS app. Here is how the EBS app is configured:

- VPC: **set to the VPC I created**
- Load balancer visibility: **I set this to public**
- Load balancer subnets: **two public subnets in the VPC**
- Public IP address: **I did not assign a public IP address for the instance**
- Instance subnets: **two private subnets in the VPC**

**Route table for both public subnets:**
[image]

**Route table for both private subnets:**
[image]

**Security group for the load balancer:**
[image]

Please let me know if you need any more information! Thank you!

Comment: Is it load balanced EB env? If yes, then ALB should be in public subnets. Can you access its url?

Comment: @Marcin hope everything is well!! It is load balanced and the load balancer is in public subnets. Is this what you are referring to? I can not access its url, it just loads forever. Thanks for the help!

Comment: HI:-) What about Security group on the ALB, does it allow http connections on port 80?

Comment: @Marcin I updated my post with the security group used for the eb instance. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: You need inboud rule allowing traffic from the internet, which is `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: @Marcin dang, I accidentally sent you the security group for the VPC of the EBS instance. I am updating my answer now. Sorry for the confusion :/

Comment: @Marcin figured out the problem. You were right, again. The ss I sent you was, again, from the wrong security group. If you post an answer saying to allow traffic from internet I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear:-) Thanks I will post answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **incorrect security groups** for ALB. Adjusting the group to allow **internet traffic** solved the issue.

Here is what the security group should have in it:
[image: t]